# How can I achieve metallic gold effect? I need to laser-print golden fonts using an OKI C9650 printer

Tags: print-design

My main difficulty is not laser-printing a large golden image, for example of a wedding ring. But I just can't get small fonts to have a metallic effect. The program I use is Corel Draw. I tried all sorts of metallic gold images and power-clipped to my fonts. The laser-printout shows shades of white, yellow and brown but doesn't look golden. I'm using "white Kraft paper" It's a heavy type of paper with one shiny side. I'd be grateful for any tips.

Comment: but the secret to metallic printing is metal. That can be an ink with something like shell gold in it (in an offset or letterpress print), foil stamping, or a thermal dot-matrix process either using a transfer ribbon or (hyper-expensive) metallized toners.

Answer (score 4):

Akin to what Stan Rogers was referring to: if you are doing a small-run (of 1), with a design that isolates text, you can use a metal foil that is designed to adhere to laser toner. Basically, you place the foil on the already printed text and use an iron to heat it. This remelts the laser printer toner and causes the foil to stick to it. Some cases, you can attache the foil and then pass it through the laser printer as a blank page to use the toner fuser unit to remelt the toner.

Check out "Metallic Heat Transfer Foils". Make sure it is for home/design use, as opposed to offset printing or industrial use.

This ( http://myrockpaperscissors.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/tips-on-using-metallic-heat-transfer-foils/ ) is a random example which may be in line with what you are thinking about.

Comment: I'd almost forgotten about that—I used to do double prints (inkjet followed by laser) quite often, either to get that "hit of varnish" look for tone-on-tone or to use a foil (although I tended to use a hot laminator rather than a (waxing) iron). Take some slack.

Answer (score 0):

When using a wax printer such as the OKI, the best you are going to get are values of yellows, siennas, browns, and whites in order to mimic a gold appearance. You will **never** get an actual gold.

If you post an image of what you have you may get some pointers on gradients and colors to use.